# SQLite multiple constraints on 1 FK

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

I have a table in SQLite with specified FK as follows:
`CONSTRAINT "model" FOREIGN KEY("category_id") REFERENCES "category"("id") deferrable initially deferred` and I need to add `ON DELETE CASCADE`. I know that in SQLite you can't add constraint with `ALTER` so how can I combine these 2 constraints when creating a new table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `CREATE` statement of the new table use:

```
CONSTRAINT model FOREIGN KEY(category_id) REFERENCES category(id) 
ON DELETE CASCADE 
DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b4c461cf9b82cdbad3ab5c30ca711e64).